# Unable ts start Bootnode, am new to private blockchian, Can anyone tell me what am i missing

Tags: private-blockchain, ethereumj, bootnodes

```
bootnode : The term 'bootnode' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, 
function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, 
or if a path was
included, verify that the path is correct and try again.
At line:1 char:1
+ bootnode -genkey boot.key
+ ~~~~~~~~
+ CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (bootnode:String) [], 
CommandNotFoundException
+ FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you don't have the bootnode command installed on your system.

I think you installed only the standard geth client. To run a bootnode you need do install the alltool version in order to have the bootnode command available.

You can find it there : [enter link description here](https://geth.ethereum.org/downloads/)